# scala Spark structured streaming Receiving duplicate message

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Kafka and Spark 2.4.5 Structured Streaming.I am doing the average operation.but i am facing issues due to getting duplicate records from the Kafka topic in a current batch.

For example ,Kafka topic message received on 1st batch batch on update mode

```
car,Brand=Honda,speed=110,1588569015000000000
car,Brand=ford,speed=90,1588569015000000000
car,Brand=Honda,speed=80,15885690150000000000

here the result is average on car brand per timestamp
i.e groupby on  1588569015000000000 and Brand=Honda , the result we got 
110+90/2 = 100

now second message received late data with the duplicate message with same timestamp
car,Brand=Honda,speed=50,1588569015000000000
car,Brand=Honda,speed=50,1588569015000000000

i am expecting average should update to 110+90+50/3 = 83.33
but result update to 110+90+50+50/4=75,which is wrong
val rawDataStream: DataFrame = spark.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
.option("subscribe", "topic1") // Both topics on same stream!
.option("startingOffsets", "latest")
.load()
.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as data")
```

group by timestamp and brand

write to kafka with checkpoint

How to use Spark Structured Streaming to do this or anything wrong on code?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to apply different logic to batch 1 and batch 2. In your first batch, You are considering duplicates on brand and timestamp to get average. But in your 2nd batch,You want to remove duplicates on brand and timestamp and then get average. Why is that difference in your logic? If it is because of speed was different in first batch for two records and same in 2nd batch then you `dropDuplicates` on brand, speed and timestamp level.

Comment: For more clarification, One of my use-case is My producer is publishing the same record two times as the late Fact or can publish same message which already calculated.That means Duplicate record can come any time. I want to drop the duplicate message which already calculated. can it be possible in structure streaming

Comment: Yes, there is a way to drop the duplicate message but for that you need to decide how do you know if a message is duplicate. Is it like if brand, speed and timestamp is repeated then it is considered as duplicate message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark Structured Streaming allows deduplication on a streaming dataframe using `dropDuplicates`. You would need to specify fields to identify a duplicate record and across batches, spark will consider only the first record per combination and records with duplicate values will be discarded.

Below snippet will deduplicate your streaming dataframe on Brand, Speed and timestamp combination.

```
rawDataStream.dropDuplicates("Brand", "speed", "timestamp")
```

Refer to spark documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#streaming-deduplication)